# Hiding default navigation bar in app on Android devices

Tags: android, react-native

Currently working on a fullscreen mobile app, building using react-native. I have managed to hide the status bar and default navigation bar on Android devices. However, when I start to put in text input tags that prompts a keyboard on the screen, the default navigation bar re-appears and could not be hidden even I've dismissed the keyboard.

Is there any way to prevent the default navigation bar re-appears when the keyboard pops up?

The reasons are that I need to remove the navigation bar to have enough space to locate the needed components on the app UI design. If the navigation bar re-appears the design will be messed up. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried to hide the navigation bar after the text input loses focus?

Comment: Does loses focus mean as in the the text input is not selected?

Comment: A clearer picture is that after inputting username and password, i dismissed the keyboard and the navigation bar is there and taking up spaces on the UI design

Comment: The way i hid the default navigation bar is by adding some lines of codes in MainActivity.java. As far as i know there is no direct way to hide it in using React-Native

Comment: Are you using any kind of navigation library?

Comment: no. The current page i am working on is just a simple login page with 2 text inputs.

Comment: Just to make the situation clearer, the navigation bar i mentioned is the default one in the Android device itself. A black bar containing three buttons. You may refer to here ( https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation ), this is where i use the code to hide the navigation bar

Comment: Yeah i understand your problem after a quick search i couldnt find a way to do it n plain react native. But im pretty sure i saw this functonality in one of the react example apps. You could still try to do this with a native module see: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for your recommendation. Will take some time to study about it. Anyhow, just discovered a way to hide back the navigation bar after it re-appears. By pulling down the notification session from the top of device and pull it back, the navigation bar appears to be hidden along with the status bar. SO, my own conclusion is there could be some flaws in either react native or android settings itself.

Comment: Hi, i have found out the reason i am getting such screen behavior. I've set the ImageBackground width to be a null value, following the size of the container. Hence when the navigation bar pops, the container gets smaller and hence taking up spaces and messed up the UI design. Now i hard coded the width to be the summation of width of the device and the height of the navigation bar (https://github.com/Sunhat/react-native-extra-dimensions-android). That seems working as i wanted but i worried about the variation of height across different devices.

Comment: anyhow the navigation bar is still appearing and its not taking up spaces. I think that is still a buggy behavior considering i am having a game app where in the chat-room, i manage to pop the keyboard on texting but the navigation bar will hidden together with the keyboard after i am done. So its possible to hide both navigation bar and keyboard together, just need to figure out the method

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
  };
```

Put this on top of each screen

Comment: its not solving my problem. Anyway i saw this line of code before, i believe this is to remove ActionBar (the top bar of android app) rather than navigation bar

Comment: Thats only for using the react-navigation module i think